# MySQL Division From Same Column with Different Keys

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with 5 fields

id  = this is autoincrementing field
form_id = this field is the form being filled out
entry_id = this is the identifier of the entry
meta_key = this is the identifier of the specific form fields
meta_value = this is the value entered into the form field

If I do a:

```
SELECT SUM(meta_value) FROM tbl WHERE meta_key = 55;
```

I get the sum of all the people who like apples.

If I do a:

```
SELECT SUM(meta_value) FROM tbl WHERE meta_key = 75;
```

I get the sum of all the people total.

I am trying to write one query that will give me the % of people who like apple so in essence `((RESULT of Q1) / (RESULT of Q2)) * 100`

So far I've looked into self joins and subqueries but I'm essentially stuck now because all the tutorials on subqueries focus on the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: The answer is so similar to what you have written, it seems plausible that you might figure this out for yourself. Nevertheless, if you're still struggling, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: ok so I'm on the right path - I'm going to play around for a bit and check this thread back in the morning. Now a days I literally almost never come here unless I'm seriously hitting dead ends but I want to try and solve this - thanks for the hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest thing I can think of:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT SUM(meta_value) FROM tbl WHERE meta_key = 55) /
    (SELECT SUM(meta_value) FROM tbl WHERE meta_key = 75) * 100
    as percentage;
```

Would that work for you?

Comment: I ended up with something very close then tried yours and it worked so I felt good I was able to get it finally lol

Answer (score 1):

You can use *conditional* aggregation

```
SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN meta_key = 55 THEN meta_value ELSE 0 END) / 
        SUM(CASE WHEN meta_key = 75 THEN meta_value ELSE 0 END)) * 100 -- be careful you may got divide by zero error
FROM tbl 
WHERE meta_key IN (55, 75);
```

However, this would produce integer division result. So, you can include `1.0` before division if you want exact result.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query, it avoid any possibility of `division by zero`, just in case `total = 0`.

```
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN b.sum_b IS NULL OR b.sum_b = 0 THEN 0
        ELSE (a.sum_a / b.sum_b) * 100
    END as percent

FROM (
    SELECT SUM(meta_value) as sum_a FROM tbl WHERE meta_key = 55
) a,

(
    SELECT SUM(meta_value) as sum_b FROM tbl WHERE meta_key = 75
) b
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid division by zero, I would simply recommend:

```
SELECT (SUM(CASE WHEN meta_key = 55 THEN meta_value ELSE 0 END) / 
        SUM(CASE WHEN meta_key = 75 THEN meta_value END)
       ) * 100 
FROM tbl 
WHERE meta_key IN (55, 75);
```

Note that the second `CASE` has no `ELSE`.  If there are no matches, then this returns `NULL`, avoiding the divide-by-zero.

That said, MySQL does not return an error for divide-by-zero.  It simply returns `NULL`.  But that is highly database-specific behavior.  I think every other database returns an error and you should be conscious of such potential issues.